# Dynamic SQL query causes "Unclosed quotation mark" error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-delete

I'm getting this error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

With the following code:

```
lSQL = "DELETE FROM tblCourses where courseCode='" + aCourseCode + "'";
```

Where `lSQL` is local variable and `aCourseCode` is a store value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance aCourseCode contains a single-quotation mark ? Please use parameterized SQL queries to protect yourself from SQL injections. Here is a good explanation http://www.uberasp.net/getarticle.aspx?id=46. Consider what that query would do if aCourseCode is the string `"x' or 1=1 --"`

Comment: Your course name is probably "A History of Sql's Vulnerabilities"

Answer (score 17):

You should **always** use parametrized queries or your code is vulnerable to errors as the one you are getting and even worse to SQL Injection attacks. **Never** use string concatenations as in your code when building SQL queries. Here's the correct way:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblCourses WHERE courseCode = @courseCode";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseCode", aCourseCode);
    int deletedRowsCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This will ensure that even if the `aCourseCode` variable contains some escape and dangerous characters they will be properly handled.

Comment: +1 Not to mention this will also escape any quotation marks in the `aCourseCode` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a single or double quote coming through in your aCourseCode variable.

Answer (score -4):

A better way to format strings is to use something like this:

```
lSQL = String.Format("DELETE FROM tblCourses where courseCode='{0}'", aCourseCode);
```

Also make sure you do not have any embedded double quotes or single quotes in your variable aCourseCode.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, this is not a better way. It suffers from the same problems as the original code.

Comment: I agree...I was giving him a way to format the string correctly not for the SQL operation.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. Of course, the point mentioned last is the more important one, but this is still sound advice. @Darin, while this won't solve the problem, it *does* make it easier to spot missing quotation marks, and thus harder to write incorrectly quoted queries. (But of course, quoting goes away once you're writing a parameterized query. It's still a useful technique in other scenarios.)

Comment: @stakx, I didn't downvote this answer but I think that the person who downvoted it wanted to make sure that other people having the same problem wouldn't ever use code like this. And I must agree with him.